# Interview question help on relatively basic JOIN and subqueries

Tags: sql-server

I was asked to:

> Print the following sequence of columns for each plant that only blooms in *one type* of weather.
>
> 1. WEATHER_TYPE
> 2. PLANT_NAME"

**Schema**

- PLANTS (table name)

  - PLANT_NAME, string, The name of the plant. This is the primary key.
  - PLANT_SPECIES, sting, The species of the plant.
  - SEED_DATE, date, The date the seed was planted.
- WEATHER (table name)

  - PLANT_SPECIES, string, The species of the plant.
  - WEATHER_TYPE, string, The type of weather in which the plant will bloom.

I wrote the script below and tested it against sample input and achieved a desired result. I don't know if this is what is considered a 'printed' result.

Seeking understanding on what I might have missed. How might I make this script 'more efficient' and/or 'better' and/or 'more robust'?

```
SELECT WEATHER.WEATHER_TYPE, a.PLANT_NAME
FROM (SELECT b.PLANT_NAME, b.PLANT_SPECIES
      FROM (SELECT PLANTS.PLANT_NAME, PLANTS.PLANT_SPECIES, PLANTS.SEED_DATE, WEATHER.WEATHER_TYPE
            FROM PLANTS JOIN WEATHER 
            ON PLANTS.PLANT_SPECIES = WEATHER.PLANT_SPECIES) b
      GROUP BY b.PLANT_NAME, b.PLANT_SPECIES
      HAVING count(*) = 1) a JOIN WEATHER
ON a.PLANT_SPECIES = WEATHER.PLANT_SPECIES
```

I achieved the expected result in a SQL Server Management Studio window, but not sure if it's the 'printed' result the question-askers are looking for.

Comment: `GROUP BY b.PLANT_NAME, b.PLANT_SPECIES` -- b.PLANT_NAME is already the PK, so no need to group by the second column.

Answer (score 3):

I personally consider CTEs easier to read and to debug, compared to nested "Table Expressions", as you have done. I would have done something like:

```
with
x as (
  select p.plant_name
  from plants p
  join weather w on w.plant_species = p.plant_species
  group by p.plant_name
  having count(*) = 1
)
select x.plant_name, w.weather_type
from x
join weather w on w.plant_species = x.plant_species
```

Comment: This certainly seems like a 'better' way to script for the need, but when I test I return an error = "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 Invalid column name 'plant_species'."

Comment: @this-aint-the-dakota

Below is the correct query:
x as (
  select p.plant_species
  from prc.plants p
  join prc.weather w on w.plant_species = p.plant_species
  group by p.plant_species
  having count(*) = 1
)
select x.plant_species, w.weather_type
from x
join weather w on w.plant_species = x.plant_species;

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with The Impaler in regards to the readability and ease of debugging nested table expressions. As another option to the CTE (which is really the better choice), if you really want to nest things without overthinking it you can use a correlated subquery. It's easier to read, though as your result set grows you'll lose efficiency.

```
SELECT w.weather_type, p.plant_name 
FROM plants p
JOIN weather w 
    ON w.plant_species = p.plant_species
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.weather WHERE plant_species = w.plant_species) = 1
```

or with grouping...

```
SELECT w.weather_type, p.plant_name 
FROM plants p
JOIN weather w 
    ON w.plant_species = p.plant_species
WHERE w.plant_species IN (SELECT plant_species FROM dbo.weather  GROUP BY plant_species HAVING COUNT(1) = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT w.weather_type, p.plant_name 
FROM plants p
JOIN weather w 
ON w.plant_species = p.plant_species
WHERE w.weather_type="Sunny";
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the corrected query as posted above by 'The Impaler':

```
x as (
select p.plant_species
from prc.plants p
join prc.weather w on w.plant_species = p.plant_species
group by p.plant_species
having count(*) = 1
)
select x.plant_species, w.weather_type
from x
join weather w on w.plant_species = x.plant_species;
```